# How to explain why I am leaving to colleagues when I do not have a new job?

Tags: colleagues, job-change, resignation

I will be leaving my current position soon, I realised the job was not for me and I did not enjoy it. However I am not leaving to go to a new or better job.  I do have a previous manager who I am able to work for. However it is a very low skilled job that I would not feel comfortable sharing with NY colleagues.

I am not sure how to avoid answering this questions on what job I am going to or why I am leaving. Though there are other things I want to do too right now such as travelling around the world and interest in working in a different environment rather than a office. How do I make this sound positive and explain my reasons?

Thank you so much.

Comment: Just say what you're saying here: you don't enjoy the current job; you want to be able to do other things - you don't have to tell them what the new job is, just that it allows you to do those things

Comment: "I want to travel around the world and work in a different environment" sounds plenty positive to me. I can imagine you want to leave if you're in a place where that's considered a bad thing.

Comment: The truth seems to be the easiest route here.

Answer (score 2):

You could be vague, or you could be specific and recite the items listed in the question above.

I'd opt for the phrase "It just wasn't a good fit, and it wasn't working out for me." and move on; if they press it while you're working, you could simply note that you have stuff to do.

If they ask you about it on personal time, maybe just say you'd rather not talk about it? It's common courtesy (At least in my culture! / US) for them to leave it alone unless you divulge those reasons.

Answer (score 0):

### Travelling the World

Tell them that you've had a great time working with them, but, you also desire to travel the world and see new things and you're not getting any younger, so you felt you had to do it now or never.

If they ask about other jobs, just say:  *"That's part of the fun of traveling around the world - I don't know what I'll be able to pick up."*

Then, just steer the conversation to your dream of traveling the world and that should do it.